# Class member of type Eigen::MatrixBase<derived> in a class? What is "derived"?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I am making a Base class and Derived class. The derived class will hold a value of `Eigen::Matrix<T,int,int>`, and inherit all of Base's methods.

I am doing this so that the methods, which are the same regardless of the matrix type, are not all repeated because of differing template args for Matrix. While these methods in the base class can be performed on a MatrixBase, I am not able to have a type of MatrixBase as a member of my Base class, because it requires a "derived " template arg.

What does "derived" refer to?

Documentation says:

> Derived is the derived type, e.g., a matrix type or an expression

I am not too sure what this means. Is there any instance of "derived" that I can fill in as the type for MatrixBase?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to achieve here. If `Base` shall have access to the matrix, make `Base` itself templated and insert the matrix there. But probably show a short example of what `Base` and what `Derived` is supposed to look like in your case.

Comment: This is the basic principle of CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern) that eigen follows, in that `MatrixBase` is an abstract class. All eigen matrices and expressions inherit from that by using `MatrixBase<Derived>` where `Derived` could be your `Eigen::Matrix<T,int,int>` for instance, or an expression involving `Eigen::Matrix<T,int,int>`.

Comment: Having said that you don't need to have a `MatrixBase` as a member of your Base class. Just use `Matrix<T,int,int>` as the member and make your Base class functions templated such that they accept `const MatrixBase<Derived>&` as an input argument. This will work for any generic eigen expression including matrices of different data types.

Comment: @romeric Consider creating an answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific situation, it may be a good idea to create an *Eigen plugin* instead of creating a new class. Eigen plugins allows you to add new methods to existing (templated) eigen classes as documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html). The different macros you can use to achieve this, are listed [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html#title4).

As chtz pointed out, the *disadvantage* of plugins is that you risk getting incompatible with libraries that use different plugins.

Comment: I would usually advice against writing Eigen plugins, unless it is really necessary, because you risk getting incompatible with libraries that use (different) plugins. Most of the times there are simpler solutions -- but I have no idea yet what the OP actually wants to do here.